# Sending Email Notification when Assigning Task to Resources in Project Server 2016 Web App

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016, project-server

I use Project server 2016 and I created a Project web app site. I created an enterprise project and entered the team data.

Now I am able to assign tasks to resources.

What I want is for the team member to be notified by email if when I assign a task to that team member.
Searching on the internet, I found, in Microsoft's site, this solution:

**Go to SharePoint Central administration, page click on under general application settings**

**click on PWA settings Manage, once the page is opened under operational policies click on alerts and reminders, set your SMTP mail server and email address.**

However, when I tried to follow these steps I have not found "Alerts and Reminders" in the "Operational Policies" section. Maybe I am missing some things at the level of Configuration?

Comment: Did you found any solution? I faced same issue not and can't find any proper way to resolve it.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/771e84d3-b89a-455f-bae2-1c4576cbadda/

Comment: Check this [Project Server 2016: Missing Alerts and Reminders Settings](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/09/23/missing-alerts-and-reminders-in-project-server-2016/)

Answer (score 1):

This way has been changed in SharePoint 2016 and it now depends on the `outgoing e-mail settings` in `Central Administration`.

For the detail steps, check [Project Server 2016: Missing Alerts and Reminders Settings.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/09/23/missing-alerts-and-reminders-in-project-server-2016/)